# Select pairs of values with unique value in one column only (SQL)

Tags: sql, vertica

I have 4 columns, like below:

```
COL1   COL1_TIME  COL2  COL2_TIME
    A   09:20:00    E   09:35:00
    A   09:20:00    F   09:36:00
    A   09:20:00    G   09:40:00
    A   09:20:00    H   09:59:00
    B   09:25:00    E   09:35:00
    B   09:25:00    F   09:36:00
    B   09:25:00    G   09:40:00
    B   09:25:00    H   09:59:00
    C   09:30:00    E   09:35:00
    C   09:30:00    F   09:36:00
    C   09:30:00    G   09:40:00
    C   09:30:00    H   09:59:00
    D   09:50:00    H   09:59:00
```

I have to select unique pairs of values from columns COL1 and COL2. To find a pair, you should take Closest time to COL1_TIME in COL2_TIME.

So the colsest time for A is E. For B its F - E is taken already etc.

Result should look like this:

```
A E
B F
C G
D H
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes those values "unique in column 3"?  I don't follow the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this as:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col4) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This guarantees that the values in column 3 are unique.  You can have duplicates in column 1.

Comment: its not what i need, i need to find first (closest to c1 time in c4) value in c3 , pair it with c1 - so the first pair is A - E , second is B - F, not A - F. Your query returns A - E, A - F, A - G, A - H , so actually i need unique pairs, not only unique value in c3

Comment: @MichałPolowczyk . . . I think you should ask another question and better explain what you really need.  Questions should not be asked in comments.

Comment: so, do you understand the problem now?